# Impromptu plugin for Alert Boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

When we use Javascript prompt Box something like this

```
 var ur_name = prompt("Enter Name");
```

We will have  two types of values in this case:

1. Value entered by user.
2. Second VALUE can be NULL, when user press CANCEL or When he presses <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> Key. Right...!

Now The problem I'm facing is: HOW to Handle escape key in Impromptu plugin of Jquery [link text](http://www.trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)

Code running perfectly When user will enter some value OR press Cancel button

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function test()
 {
var txt = 'Please enter your name:<br /> <input type="text" id="alertName" name="alertName" value="name here" />';

 $.prompt(txt,{
callback: mycallbackform,
buttons: { OK: 'Hello', Cancel: 'Good Bye' }
  });
}

 function mycallbackform(v,m,f){
  if(v=="Hello")     
   $.prompt("Stack Over flow User:"+' ' + f.alertName);
  }
 </script>
```

Cause in this scenario I'm  getting cancel or OK button key pressed events, but when user press <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> key **mycallbackform** will not be called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I have always used the jQueryUI .dialog function to provide user dialogs which has the `closeOnEscape` option. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

If you have your heart set on using impromptu it should be fairly easy to implement some event handling using the jQuery function keyup -

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".prompt").hide();
    }
});
```